# nuxt/vue route url to hashed-url

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

didn't manage to find much on this, but I am using anchors on my website, hence I will get a URL as such
`localhost:3000/#about`.

I am wondering if it's possible to route a URL as such `localhost:3000/about` to the hashed URL `localhost:3000/#about` without having a physical about-page.

Essentially, when I directly access the absolute link, I am routed to the hashed/anchored page.

Comment: You need to do this on the server-side. What about a redirect?

Comment: That should be fine. How would i go about doing a redirect?

Comment: It depends on what you use on your server-side.